# Switch' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Please solve this problem**
Switch' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

The code is:

```
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/services' component={Services} />
        <Route path='/products' component={Products} />
        <Route path='/contact-us' component={ContactUs} />
        <Route path='/sign-up' component={SignUp} />
        <Route path='/marketing' component={Marketing} />
        <Route path='/consulting' component={Consulting} />
      </Switch>
    Is there anything to install or?
```

Comment: Is Switch imported? Need more context

Comment: `import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import every module in a right way as below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom";

// import your components here ...
import Home from './Home'
...




class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/services" component={Services} />
          <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
          <Route path="/contact-us" component={ContactUs} />
          <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
          <Route path="/marketing" component={Marketing} />
          <Route path="/consulting" component={Consulting} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can't import Switch, export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Answer (score 1):

you couldn't import Switch Component